# How to pass GDAL CLI arguments when exporting a GeoTIFF with rioxarray

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio, gdal-translate, rioxarray

I have a routine that create a mosaic from COPDEM 30M and I need to export it passing an argument to it.

The argument: `-mo AREA_OR_POINT=AREA --config GTIFF_POINT_GEO_IGNORE True`

The behavior I expect is the half pixel shift to NW, according to the RFC 33: [GDAL RFC 33](https://gdal.org/development/rfc/rfc33_gtiff_pixelispoint.html)

Running gdal_translate from QGIS is fine and works just I expect, but exporting a raster with `rio.to_raster` method as the following, produces a raster with the AREA_OR_POINT setted to 1 (AREA), but the pixels aren't shifted to NW.

Python command: `dem.rio.to_raster("data/copdem_30m/mosaic_AREA.tif", tags = {"AREA_OR_POINT": "AREA"}, GTIFF_POINT_GEO_IGNORE = True)`

What is wrong with this command, since this is just what is specified in the documentation: [rioxarray rio.to_raster](https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/rioxarray.html#rioxarray.raster_dataset.RasterDataset.to_raster)?

The problem can be reproduced with the following scene: https://prism-dem-open.copernicus.eu/pd-desk-open-access/prismDownload/COP-DEM_GLO-30-DGED__2022_1/Copernicus_DSM_10_S17_00_W045_00.tar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set GDAL config options inside a [`rasterio.Env`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/image_options.html#options) context manager:

```py
import rioxarray
import rasterio


dem = rioxarray.open_rasterio(
    "Copernicus_DSM_10_S17_00_W045_00/DEM/Copernicus_DSM_10_S17_00_W045_00_DEM.tif",
)
with rasterio.Env(GTIFF_POINT_GEO_IGNORE=True):
    dem.rio.to_raster("data/copdem_30m/mosaic_AREA.tif", tags = {"AREA_OR_POINT": "AREA"})
```

Answer (score 1):

As you mention and as noted in the [GDAL GeoTiff documentation](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html#configuration-options), GTIFF_POINT_GEO_IGNORE is a GDAL configuration option, not a part of the image profile.

[GDAL configuration options](https://gdal.org/user/configoptions.html) can be specified by setting an environment variable with that name/value before calling `rio.to_raster`, like this:

```
os.environ["GTIFF_POINT_GEO_IGNORE"] = "TRUE"
dem.rio.to_raster("data/copdem_30m/mosaic_AREA.tif", tags = {"AREA_OR_POINT": "AREA"})
```